# How to import more than 1 (multiple) images in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I can only import one image into kivy but if i tried to import more than one it gets an error saying, "Only one root object is allowed by .kv"

main.py

```
  import kivy
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
  from kivy.lang import Builder

  lol = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

  class Myapp(App):
      def build(self):
          return lol



  if __name__== "__main__":
      Myapp().run()
```

my.kv

```
  Image:
          source: 'equalizer.gif'
          size_hint: 0.3, 0.4
          pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

  Image:
          source: 'themp.png'
          pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'top': 1}
          size_hint: None, None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message kivy only allows to have a root since kivy only supports one window, so if you want to show several items then you must use a container, for example a BoxLayout:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Image:
        source: 'equalizer.gif'
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.4
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

    Image:
        source: 'themp.png'
        pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'top': 1}
        size_hint: None, None
```